# Attach a Click event to SPServices.SPAutocomplete

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices

I am using SPAutocomplete for a type ahead input text box as shown below. This works great.

```
      $().SPServices.SPAutocomplete({
        sourceList: "mySourceList",
        sourceColumn: "mySourceColumn",
        columnName: "DestinationColumn",
        ignoreCase: true,
        numChars: 3,
        slideDownSpeed: 'fast'
    });
```

I want to write an onChange event on the input text box. Which works only when I type in the input text box and does not work with the autocomplete. I also tried KeyUp, KeyDown, KeyPress - with e=13 which did not work either.

```
    $('input[title="DestinationColumn"]').on('change', function () {
       // Logic here            
    });
```

Finally I am trying to attach the click event to the ul list items that dynamically generate during type ahead. Logic here. This is not working either.

```
   $('ul[id^="SPAutocomplete_DestinationColumn"] li').on('click', function () {
       // Logic here
    });
```

How can I write an onchange event with auto populate select on an input textbox? Any clues will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I figured out issue, I attached the click event directly to the ul instead of ul li elements.

```
$('ul[id^="SPAutocomplete_DestinationColumn"]').on('click', function () {
   // at this point, the input text box holds the auto complete value that was clicked. this solved my issue. 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was driving me crazy. 4 hours thrown away. :)